# How to set the tint color of iPhone calendar cancel and done buttons

Tags: objective-c, iphone, eventkit

I have implemented the native event calendar in my application. I am able to display the calendar shown in the screenshot below by using the following code:

```
EKEventEditViewController *eventEditViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
eventEditViewController.editViewDelegate = self;
eventEditViewController.event = event;
[self presentViewController:eventEditViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`
```

However, I am not able to change the color of the Cancel and Done buttons. How can I change the color of these buttons for the calendar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the navigationBar.barStyle.  I set mine to be UIBarStyleBlackOpaque and it made the white buttons show up nicely.

```
nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:eventController];
nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
nc.navigationBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Answer (score 0):

try set your navigation controller tint color

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

or customize bar button item with desired color?

Comment: This is not going to work, the view controller was presented on a navigation but it was never pushed so it doesn't know it parent, in another words navigationController it always nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tint color for all your navigation controllers for example:
on AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`